# Efficient python for loop for many variables

Tags: python, numpy, cpython

Given `p` integer variables `k_1,..., k_p`, I would like to loop over all possible values of `k_i (i=1 to p)` such that `k_i>=1 (i= 1 to p)` and `k_1+k_2+...+k_{p-1}+k_p<= m` (where `m` is an integer greater than `p`). How could I efficiently do this loop in python?

I tried:

```
for idx in itertools.product(range(1,m-1+1),repeat=p)
```

It already takes some time for `m=10` and `p=m-1=9`. Must be possible to do much better.

Comment: What exactly takes some time? Generating that range or what you do with it?

Comment: You tagged this with `numpy`, which is indeed a good way to loop at C speed, but you'll need to provide detail on exactly what work you're doing within the loop body.

Comment: Let's say you want to calculate f(idx) (where f is some function). For a simple example, one could think of doing sum(idx). This one already takes some time for m=10 and p=9.

Comment: No wonder it takes a long time, you are performing 387420489 iterations of that loop. Is idx meant to point at a position within an p dimensional array? If so you could look at using meshgrid to produce the corresponding numpy index array.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `itertools.product` function and adapt it to your needs. 
Because of the condition `k_1+k_2+...+k_{p-1}+k_p <= m`, instead of calculating all possible combinations in the cartesian product and filter afterwards, `break` the loop each time the sum already goes beyond your limit `m`, since adding a bigger integer instead in the next iteration will also pass over the limit. Depending on your input numbers it will be much faster.

The original source:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

I would try something along these lines:

```
def product2(*args, **kwds):
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        temp = [[]]
        for x in result:
            for y in pool:
                z = x+[y]
                if sum(z) > m:
                    break
                else:
                    temp.append(z)
        result = temp
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Test (runs fast):

```
m = 10
p = 9
k = range(1,m-1+1)
for x in product2(k,repeat=p):
    print x
```

Not sure if you want only tuples of exactly `p` values, though, but you seem to expect the same behavior as with `product`, so here it is.